# How to import large dataset and put it in a single column

Tags: matlab, import, multiple-columns

I want to import the large data set (multiple column) by using the following code. I want to get all in a single column instead only one row (multi column). So i did transpose operation but it still doesn't work appropriately.

```
    clc
    clear all 
    close all 
    dataX_Real = fopen('dataX_Real_in.txt');dataX_Real=dataX_Real';
```

I will really appreciate your support and suggestions. Thank You
The sample files can be found using the following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzh0lxbio7mfnqb/dataX_Real_in.txt?dl=0).

Comment: `fopen` doesn't import the content of the files. It only opens the file so the data can be imported by other functions. I suggest you use `dataX_Real = dlmread('dataX_Real_in.txtx');`. (For `dlmread` you don't have to call `fopen` first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `fopen`, all you are doing is opening up the file. You **aren't reading in the data**.  What is returned from `fopen` is actually a file pointer that gives you access to the contents of the file.  It doesn't actually read in the contents itself.  You would need to use things like `fread` or `fscanf` to read in the content from the text data.

However, I would recommend you use [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) instead, as this doesn't require a `fopen` call to open your file.  This will open up the file, read the contents and store it into a variable in one function call:

```
dataX_Real = dlmread('dataX_Real_in.txt');
```

By doing the above and using your text file, I get 44825 elements.  Here are the first 10 entries of your data:

```
>> format long;
>> dataX_Real(1:10)

ans =

  Columns 1 through 4

  -0.307224970000000   0.135961950000000  -1.072544100000000   0.114566020000000

  Columns 5 through 8

   0.499754310000000  -0.340369000000000   0.470609910000000   1.107567700000000

  Columns 9 through 10

  -0.295783020000000  -0.089266816000000
```

Seems to match up with what we see in your text file!  However, you said you wanted it as a single column.  This by default reads the values in on a row basis, so here you can certainly transpose:

```
dataX_Real = dataX_Real.';
```

Displaying the first 10 elements, we get:

```
>> dataX_Real = dataX_Real.';
>> dataX_Real(1:10)

ans =

  -0.307224970000000
   0.135961950000000
  -1.072544100000000
   0.114566020000000
   0.499754310000000
  -0.340369000000000
   0.470609910000000
   1.107567700000000
  -0.295783020000000
  -0.089266816000000
```

Comment: "textread" seems handy but scanning is very slow. Is there any alternative for faster data reading? Thanks

Comment: @ibrahimkbd - Try `dlmread`.  I've modified my answer.  Credit goes to @hbaderts.  I just tried it and it's much faster.  `textread` is for more generic text files.  `dlmread` is good for numeric data, which is what we have here.